# How to access Extjs nested models (loaded from Xml)?

Tags: xml, model, extjs4

Having difficulty getting my head around the 'Associations' feature of Models and how
a developer can access the nested data through the association.

Here's a simple XML file we're trying to parse.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<contacts>
    <contact>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Bob Jones</name>
        <emails>
            <email>
                <addr>bjones1@dom.com</addr>
                <display>B. Jones 1</display>
            </email>
            <email>
                <addr>bjones2@dom.com</addr>
                <display>B. Jones 2</display>
            </email>
        </emails>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>John Rodeo</name>
        <emails>
            <email>
                <addr>jrodeo1@dom.com</addr>
                <display>J. Rodeo 1</display>
            </email>
            <email>
                <addr>jrodeos2@dom.com</addr>
                <display>J. Rodeo 2</display>
            </email>
        </emails>
    </contact>
</contacts>
```

And here's the related Models

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Contact', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    uses: [
        'MyApp.model.Emails'
    ],

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'id'
        },
        {
            name: 'name'
        }
    ],

    hasMany: {
        model: 'MyApp.model.Emails',
        autoLoad: true,
        foreignKey: 'addr',
        name: 'emailAddresses'
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.Emails', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    uses: [
        'MyApp.model.Contact'
    ],

    idProperty: 'addr',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'addr'
        },
        {
            name: 'display'
        }
    ],

    belongsTo: {
        model: 'MyApp.model.Contact'
    }
});
```

And finally, here's the store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyXmlStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.Contact'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: true,
            storeId: 'MyXmlStore',
            model: 'MyApp.model.Contact',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data/data.xml',
                reader: {
                    type: 'xml',
                    record: 'contact'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

We created a simple Grid and link it to the Store...and presto,
it shows the contacts (quick ascii rendering)

```
+---------------------------+
| My Grid Panel             |
+-----+---------------------+
| Id  | Name                |
+-----+---------------------+
|  1  | Bob Jones           |
|  2  | John Rodeo          |
```

But we are at a complete loss as to how to retrieve the associated Email
records.

I've read that the GridPanel may not be able to correctly render associated
data. That's no problem for us -- we're just trying to get our heads around 
how we can access it programatically using this mock-up data.

For example, let's say we wanted to create a simple onXmlstoreLoad event attached 
to the store and we wanted to just console.log() the email addresses after loading 
-- What would be the correct syntax?

We've tried the recommended approach:

```
onXmlstoreLoad: function(store, records, successful, operation, options) {
    console.log(store.emailAddresses.getAt(0));
}
```

But this results in an undefined reference.

I recognize it may boil down to us describing our Models incorrectly, but we've tried
dozens of different configurations and can't figure out whether or not the problem
is the data's not getting into the store...or whether or not we can't refer to is
syntactically correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out what I was missing to be able to successfully read nested models correctly. Once we populated our store correctly, it was a simple matter to access the nested data records.

The key bit we were missing had todo with the Proxy/reader.  EACH of the Model's needs to have their own Proxy reader so you can specify the 'record' and 'root' parameters.

I recommend anyone who stumbles across this thread check out the excellent site maintained by  Neil McGuigan -- http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.com/2012_05_01_archive.html. There is tons of important tips & best practices you should follow.

One important clue Neil provided to our solution was that developers should hang Proxy's and Readers off Models, not off the store.  This made it simple to manage the Xml specific record/root parameters.

Whew this was a tough one...to anyone who's first entering the deep end of Extjs, I strongly recommend you get up close an personal with Firebug. Stepping into the extjs source code started to answer alot of important questions about how the various bits & pieces fit together.

The extjs code base is extremely well documented. And although the developers are clearly black-belts in Javascript which occasionally makes it a challenge to follow where they are going, the end result is well worth the effort.

In case you're looking for working code...

Our Store

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyXmlStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.Contact'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: true,
            storeId: 'MyXmlStore',
            model: 'MyApp.model.Contact',
            listeners: {
                load: {
                    fn: me.onXmlstoreLoad,
                    scope: me
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    },

    onXmlstoreLoad: function(store, records, successful, operation, options) {
        console.log("onXmlstoreLoad:"+ successful);
        console.log(s.getAt(0).emailAddressesStore.getAt(0));

    }

});
```

And our Models

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Contact', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    uses: [
        'MyApp.model.Emails'
    ],

    fields: [
        {
            mapping: 'id',
            name: 'id',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            mapping: 'name',
            name: 'name',
            type: 'string'
        }
    ],

    hasMany: {
        associationKey: 'emails',
        model: 'MyApp.model.Emails',
        name: 'emailAddresses'
    },

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data/data.xml',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'contacts',
            record: 'contact'
        }
    }
});
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Emails', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    uses: [
        'MyApp.model.Contact'
    ],

    fields: [
        {
            mapping: 'addr',
            name: 'addr',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            mapping: 'display',
            name: 'display',
            type: 'string'
        }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data/data.xml',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'emails',
            record: 'email'
        }
    },

    belongsTo: {
        model: 'MyApp.model.Contact'
    }
});
```